# How to close the excel file in selenium java before writing to the file?

Tags: java, selenium, export-to-excel

I have a selenium test script in Java thats reads from and write to excel file. The problem is that it can't write to the file if it is already open. I want my script to close the file automatically before writing to the file in case the user forgets to close the excel file.

Below is the code that opens the excel file to read from it and I have no problem reading from the file even if the file is already open

```
// prepare excel file       
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new
File(r.CONFIG.getProperty("testCaseFile")));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(6);  
sheetmyWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ZipCodeEntry"))).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(row).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
```

Below is  the code that writes to the excel file. The script will hang here if a user forgets to close the excel file before running the script. I am trying to find a way to add a code here that will close the file before executing the code below

```
//write random first name to the same file
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(4).setCellValue(randomFirstName);
//write test result to the same file
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(25).setCellValue(testResult);
//write confirmation to the same file
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(23).setCellValue(confirmation); //write the confirmation number in the excel file
//write premium to the same file
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(24).setCellValue(premium); //write premium in the excel file
//enter timestamp
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(27).setCellValue(r.timeStamp());
//enter environment
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(26).setCellValue(r.CONFIG.getProperty("environment"));
FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(r.CONFIG.getProperty("testCaseFile")));
workbook.write(outFile);
outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually a writeLock on a file is exclusive, so in order to get it, no other locks should be on the file (handled by the OS). 
I don't think there is a way to programmatically workaround this as this.

why not just write your content to a new file?

Comment: I wanted to write it to a new file but the users want to keep everything on the same file.

Comment: then add a warning popup or output that the user has to close the file before running the script or do a preCheck if you get a writeLock and warn the user accordingly